# Constructing a JSON value to POST as part of HTTP request

Tags: go

I'm currently attempting to build a variable, convert it to JSON and use it to post to my database.

However, every time I try to post the data it's returning a 'JSON is not valid' error, indicating it's not constructed right.

I need to pass in two variables, which are initialised as part of the request by being passed in as query values.

Does anyone know why my JSON isn't valid?

Here's my code:

```
dataString := string(` { "credentials_id": "12345", "user_id": "12", "variable1": ` + variable1 + `, "variable2": ` + variable2 + ` }`)

    fmt.Println(dataString)

    req, err = http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api-call-url/bla", strings.NewReader(finalDataString))

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        fmt.Println("Error was not equal to nil at first stage.")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    req.Header.Add("apikey", os.Getenv("APIKEY"))
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+os.Getenv("APIKEY"))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Prefer", "return=representation")

    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error posting data to database.")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    respBody, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    w.Write(respBody)
```

Comment: When custom making the JSON you are printing the variable1 and variable2 into the string however I am assuming they are strings and you aren't adding the quotation marks "".

Answer (score 3):

You should `json.Marshal` the payload data as shown in these [examples](https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-json-marshal-example.html).

So something like:

```
import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/json"
        "net/http"
)

[...]

payload, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "credentials_id": "12345",
        "user_id":        "12",
        "variable1":      variable1,
        "variable2":      variable2,
})

req, err = http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api-call-url/bla", bytes.NewReader(payload))

[...]

defer resp.Body.Close()

respBody, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

var data interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(respBody), &data)
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/madrisan/go-mattermost-notify/blob/main/mattemost/methods.go#L30).

Comment: So it posts using this code, but it doesn't extract the variable 1 and 2. It just posts them as plain strings - I need to access the actual values of them!

Comment: I've got it.... If I put it into a map type I can omit the + to join them together. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I do not look too match at this part of your code. Fixed